# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Registerd_Users has no column named userType

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

(EDIT: After various attempts at getting the code working... Nothing. After a few suggestions that didn't work, I'm still looking for an answer:)

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FNAME = "fullName";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "userEmail";
private static final String KEY_PASS = "passWord";
private static final String KEY_TYPE = "userType";
```

However on running, the program tells me there is no such column as UserType.
Here is the code for both Java Class files.

**DatabaseHandler.Java**

```
package com.set.ultimax.login;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Users";

private static final String TABLE_USERS = "Registerd_Users";

// Account Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FNAME = "fullName";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "userEmail";
private static final String KEY_PASS = "passWord";
private static final String KEY_TYPE = "userType";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ACCOUNT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PASS + " TEXT " + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ACCOUNT_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
    onCreate(db);// Create tables again
}

// Adding new User
void addUsers(Users users) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FNAME, users.getFname()); //full name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, users.getEmail()); // Email
    values.put(KEY_PASS, users.getPassword()); // Password
    values.put(KEY_TYPE, users.getuserType()); //user Type

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
public void deleteAll() //Deletes all data in the database
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_USERS,null,null);
}

public boolean validateUser(String fullName, String userEmail, String password, String userType){
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE "
                    + KEY_FNAME + "='" + fullName + "'AND "
                    + KEY_EMAIL + "='" + userEmail +"'AND "
                    + KEY_PASS + "='" + password + "'AND "
                    + KEY_TYPE + "='" + userType + "'" ,  null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else{return false;}

}
public boolean sameUser(String userEmail){
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE "
                    + KEY_EMAIL + "='" + userEmail + "'" ,  null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else{return false;}
}

}
```

**SignUp.Java**

```
package com.set.ultimax.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUp extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

    TextView goHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home);
    Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);

    goHome.setPaintFlags(goHome.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

    goHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            Intent toMain = new Intent(SignUp.this, Main.class);
            startActivity(toMain);
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(v.getContext());
            Intent toMain = new Intent(SignUp.this, Main.class);
            EditText fName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fName);
            EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
            EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            String fNameValue = fName.getText().toString();
            String emailValue = email.getText().toString();
            String passValue = pass.getText().toString();

            int charemailLength = emailValue.length();
            int charPassLength = passValue.length();
            boolean emailMatch = db.sameUser(emailValue);

            if (emailMatch) { //Checks to see if the UserName already exists
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "UserName Already Taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (emailValue.equals("") && passValue.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Fields Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (charemailLength <= 5 && charPassLength <= 5) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Characters too short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            else {
                db.addUsers(new Users(fNameValue, emailValue, passValue,"Admin" ));
                startActivity(toMain);
            }

        }

    });

}
}
```

I've been playing with the code for roughly 5 hours and through my blinkered exhaustion, I cannot see what's wrong. Any help would be great.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Try to uninstall your app and install it again.Becuase I can not see any error

Comment: I did that, it didn't work, thanks for the response though

Answer (score 0):

```
        + KEY_PASS + " TEXT " + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT" + ")";
                           ^^
```

Missing comma.

Comment: How did you see that!? I'll retry it and and tell you how I got on. Thank you so much by the way!